# How many builds/Jobs we can run parallely at a time on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How many builds/Jobs we can run parallely at a time on jenkins.

Comment: You should consider marking questions "answered" for those that helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins can run as many jobs as you have available "executors". You can change the number of executors at will in the configuration.

The real question is: how many jobs can your **hardware** handle. This depends entirely on your hardware specs **and** and type of jobs you are running (maven compilation, xcode build, script jobs).

Plus, each job goes through different stages: there is the **SCM checkout stage**, which will be harddisk IO and network IO heavy, there is the **build stage** which will be CPU and/or Memory heavy, there is the **archiving stage**, which will be harddisk (but not network) IO heavy [and this depends if you are archiving locally or over the network].

All these stages in parallel jobs rarely happen at the same time. For example: your hardware may only be able to support 5 parallel SCM checkout stages due to network bandwidth limitation, but since this would rarely happen at the same time, you will be safe running 10 jobs in parallel.

Finally, it is very unlikely that all your jobs are exactly the same with the same load profile.

So, unless every single one of your jobs is exactly the same, with exactly the same load profile, and you specify your hardware specs, and your describe the load profile for this job (bandwidth required, CPU utilization, etc), nobody could answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your servers specifications but try not to run more